# How to create a JPEG 2000 sequence with alpha channel with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I create a JPEG 2000 sequence preserving the alpha of an input video with FFmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/movie_with_alpha.mov -c:v jpeg2000 -pix_fmt rgba /output/path/sequence_%04d.jp2
```

… throws this info:

```
Incompatible pixel format 'rgba' for codec 'jpeg2000', auto-selecting format 'rgb24'
```

I tried other options for `-pix_fmt` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use libopenjpeg instead

FFmpeg supports two JPEG 2000 encoders: *libopenjpeg* and *jpeg2000*. libopenjpeg supports alpha:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libopenjpeg output_%04d.jp2
```

- Your `ffmpeg` must be compiled with `--enable-libopenjpeg` to use this encoder.
- The encoder jpeg2000 does **not** support alpha. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=jpeg2000`. None of the supported pixel formats have an `a` in their name, so it does not support alpha.

Comment: How can I do a lossy compression? I found `-compression_level` but I am looking for something like an adaptive bitrate like `-crf` for `h.264.

Comment: @florit Should be asked as a new question.